# How to resolve this compilation error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opengl, fopen

I'm tring to compile some OpenGl code as I'm getting this error

`1>c:\users\student\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\openglproject1\openglproject1\initshader.h(10): error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.`

The program is

```
#include "Angel.h"

namespace Angel {

// Create a NULL-terminated string by reading the provided file
static char*
readShaderSource(const char* shaderFile)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(shaderFile, "r");

    if ( fp == NULL ) { return NULL; }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char* buf = new char[size + 1];
    fread(buf, 1, size, fp);

    buf[size] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    return buf;
}


// Create a GLSL program object from vertex and fragment shader files
GLuint
InitShader(const char* vShaderFile, const char* fShaderFile)
{
    struct Shader {
    const char*  filename;
    GLenum       type;
    GLchar*      source;
    }  shaders[2] = {
    { vShaderFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, NULL },
    { fShaderFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();


    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    Shader& s = shaders[i];
    s.source = readShaderSource( s.filename );
    if ( shaders[i].source == NULL ) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read " << s.filename << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( s.type );

    glShaderSource( shader, 1, (const GLchar**) &s.source, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );

    GLint  compiled;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );
    if ( !compiled ) {
        std::cerr << s.filename << " failed to compile:" << std::endl;
        GLint  logSize;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize );
        char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
        std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
        delete [] logMsg;

        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    delete [] s.source;

    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    }

    /* link  and error check */
    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint  linked;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );
    if ( !linked ) {
    std::cerr << "Shader program failed to link" << std::endl;
    GLint  logSize;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);
    char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
    glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logSize, NULL, logMsg );
    std::cerr << logMsg << std::endl;
    delete [] logMsg;

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    /* use program object */
    glUseProgram(program);

    return program;
}

}  // Close namespace Angel block
```

Can you tell me how I must modify the program?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2575116/10077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define [`_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the header file that generates the error, before including the header file or apply it to the entire project by adding it to the project settings in "Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions".

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "initshader.h"

//... your code here
```

If you are using pre-compiled headers and the header generating the errors is included in `stdafx.h` you will need to add it to the `stdafx.h` header or add in your project settings as described above.