# 'too few argument in function call' (visual studio). i cant open the file. How to solve this?

Tags: c

'too few argument in function call' (visual studio). i cant open the file. How to solve this?

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen_s("testfile.txt", "w"); //to open file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the first thing you need to do is work out the difference between C#, C and C++, because you are obviously confused... Note, you used the C# tag (which in turn brings a bunch of C# professionals and enthusiasts to eagerly visit a question full of C# goodness, only to leave bitterly disappointed) :)

Comment: Change `fopen_s` to `fopen`.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575116/fopen-fopen-s-and-writing-to-files

Comment: visual studio should use 'fopen_s'

Answer (score 1):

`Too few arguments in function call` means that you called a function (`fopen_s` in this case) with 2 arguments, but the function requires 3 arguments.

How to solve? Simply search and read the [documentation for `fopen_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160). Often enough, there are also examples of usage.

After reading the docs, you will find out that this is how you use `fopen_s()`:

```c
int main(void) {
  FILE* fp = NULL;

  if (fopen_s(&fp, "testfile.txt", "w") != 0 || fp == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: cannot open file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  ...
}
```